# Два задания с указателями на C++

Tags: c++, указатели

Посмотрите пожалуйста правильно ли я делаю?

1.Напишите код изменяющий значение указателя:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
 int i = 10;
 int *p = &i;
 *p = 5;

 std::cout << *p;

}
```

2.Напишите код для изменения значения, на которое указывает указатель:

```
 #include <iostream>
    int main(){
     int i = 10;
     int *p = &i;
     i = 5;
     std::cout << *p;

    }
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что домашние задания надо делать самому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что от вас хотят
в первом случае

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int i = 10, j = 20;
    int *p = &i;

    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
    p = &j;
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
```

Ну, а во втором -

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int i = 10;
    int *p = &i;

    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    *p = 20;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```